# Best multi-objective 3D path optimization algorithm?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm, path-finding

I would like to calculate 3D balanced paths to building exits at once, for huge amount of people (2000). Since the problem is related to evacuation and solutions for 3D paths (the fastest and others) can be precalcualted and I am going to store 3D paths in database to accelerate the process. As I see it, there are two solutions so far:

1. Calculation of a number of passing through nodes, in graph environment representation, but probably the time calculation will be intolerable.
2. Using GA. However, I cannot find a good described optimization example, where is used genetic algorithm.

Can you tell me a way of using GA for multiobjective optimization, because I found only implementation of GA for finding shortest path? and Which algorithm is the best for multi-object optimization?

Comment: Have you looked at "max flow min cut?"  It is not specifically a 3d path optimizer, but it sounds like your problem may be better described as a flow problem, and that algorithm is quite efficient at what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genetic Algorithm as it is cannot be easily used for multi-objective optimisation directly. If you want to use the purest GA you have to combine the objectives into a single objective, e.g. by summing weighted values of each objective. But this often does not work very well, especially when there is a strong tradeoff between the objectives.

However, there are genetic (evolutionary) algorithms designed specifically for multi-objective optimisation. Probably the most famous one and one of the best is the [NSGA-II](http://www.iitk.ac.in/kangal/Deb_NSGA-II.pdf) which stands for **N**ondominated **S**orting **G**enetic **A**lgorithm **II**. It's also relatively easy to implement (I did once). But there other MOEAs (**M**ulti-**O**bjective **E**volutionary **A**lgorithm) too, just google it. Some of them also use the nondomination idea, others not.

Comment: Thank you for help! I would like to know, how fast is NSGA-II algorithm and what is the recommended number of objectives for a fast processing?

Comment: @MitkoAleksandrov Well, you can find the complexity in the paper. How fast it is depends on the problem being solved, number of objectives, your genetic operators and a load of other things. You have to try. The number of objectives is given by the problem, isn't it? But of course the less objectives the faster it should be. It can handle any number of objectives.